# How do you programmatically call jQuery's ajax processData function?

Tags: jquery

jQuery has a method that is automatically called prior to the success callback of an ajax request. How do you go about invoking this method on any arbitrary server response?

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `param`-function documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

> **jQuery.param( obj ):** Create a serialized representation of an array or
>   object, suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

This is what jQuery does internally:

```
// Convert data if not already a string
if ( s.data && s.processData && typeof s.data !== "string" ) {
  s.data = jQuery.param( s.data, s.traditional );
}
```

You can read the full the source here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not too sure of what u want u can do something like this

You can use json.

And in the php u can do something like send an array which contains a variable with some definite value like `fine` and then on js side in success function u can first check if the variable is the same or not. 
And if it is not then u can do what u want when the server returns an arbitrary response.